# Online bitcoin tools playground?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, client

Currently I'm reading a great book [Mastering Bitcoin](https://www.bitcoinbook.info/) and the author on his first articles suggests to the reader build from the source [Bitcoin Core](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.git) environment and down load the whole blockchain ledger (about 60Gb) to my local storage to be able perform common queries. But it's to long way for me.

So, is there any where on Internet already exist an online `bitcoin-cli` command line tool where I could practice?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is chainquery which allows you to try some cli commands online. Not all commands are available, but it's a good start to get your feet wet. https://chainquery.com/bitcoin-api

Answer (score 2):

You can try practicing on the testnet. It is a bitcoin network specifically developed for testing purposes. The blockchain size is also not huge for the testnet 
[This](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#testnet) link is the official documentation and would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this site is close enough to what you are looking for?  https://bitpay.github.io/bitcore-playground/app/#/units